# Google Sheets Subtract Consecutive Columns Arrayformula ISBLANK

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to subtract consecutive columns of dates with arrayformula

```
 07May2020 08Jun2020 09Jul2020 10Aug2020 11Sep2020
 10Oct2020 11Nov2020 21Dec2020
 10May2020 15Jul2020 18Aug2020 21Sep2020
```

I used this formula

```
=arrayformula(if(isblank(F2:G),"",G2:G-F2:F))
```

This resulted in two columns of same result on every output. How to combine all columns with arrayformula?

Sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wmLc3-7vesY0ipZMxhOyT3K0pUePtZEVeCEdG3XcGWw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do you have a sample sheet or an image indicating your desired output? The formula you posted will only subtract dates on columns F and G.

Comment: @CarlosM Hi, attached sheet, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the `arrayformula` to check if the column with the later date is empty, then apply the subtraction to the arrays:

```
=arrayformula(if(isblank(B1:F),"",B1:F-A1:E))
```

In your sample spreadsheet:

[image]

Reference: [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)

Comment: much appreciated :)